# Posting a form from a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a modal which I will be using extensively on many different pages and hence I thought putting it in a partial view was appropriate.  Within the modal is a form but I'm just getting a 'can't find action on controller error' whenever I try submit the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPlayerSignup", "SignupSheet", new {id = Model.Id, slug = Model.Slug}))
{
  @Html.DropDownList("Member", Model.SignupSheet.GroupMembers, new {label = "Members"})
  @Html.Hidden("SignupSheetId", Model.SignupSheet.Id)
  @Html.Hidden("ModalId", Model.ModalId)
  @Html.SubmitButton("Add", true, new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})
}
```

The weird thing is it's not even saying it can't find `addplayersignup` on `signupsheetcontroller`, it's saying it cant find `list` on `ladder` which is the source of the partial view.

Is posting forms from a partial view not supported or something?

Comment: Does your main view also have any form tags (sounds like you have nested forms which is invalid)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you forgot to add a form method,...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPlayerSignup", "SignupSheet",FormMethod.Post ,new {id = Model.Id, slug = Model.Slug}))
```

That should do the trick

Comment: OP is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29) where the default is `FormMethod.Post`